# Nested Query in Phalcon

Tags: phalcon

I have three tables and the ER diagram is shown as followed
[image]

The field "f" in table "dNodes" contains floating point number. My first work is to collect those records in "dNodes" having "f" value 3, so the phql for this task would be `SELECT * FROM dNodes WHERE dNodes.f = 3`

I then want to collect records from "neighbours" where both "aInd" and "bInd" match the result from my first work. In terms of sql, I can use either

`SELECT * FROM neighbours AS n WHERE n.aInd IN (SELECT a.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS a WHERE a.f = 3) AND n.bInd IN (SELECT b.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS b WHERE b.f = 3)`

or

`SELECT n.* FROM neighbours AS n INNER JOIN (SELECT aa.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS aa WHERE aa.f = 3) AS a ON n.aInd = a.nodeInd INNER JOIN (SELECT bb.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS bb WHERE bb.f = 3) AS b ON n.bInd = b.nodeInd;`

They both give me the same and correct result in MySQL. To collect such data through Phalcon RESTful web service, I use the following code:

```
$app->get('/neighbours', function() use ($app){
$phql = "SELECT n.* FROM neighbours AS n INNER JOIN (SELECT aa.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS aa WHERE aa.f = 3) AS a ON n.aInd = a.nodeInd INNER JOIN (SELECT bb.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS bb WHERE bb.f = 3) AS b ON n.bInd = b.nodeInd;";
$neis = $app->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);

$data = array();
foreach($neis as $nei){
    $data[] = array(
        "aInd" => $nei->aInd,
        "bInd" => $nei->bInd,
        "distance" => $nei->distance
    );
}

echo json_encode($data);
});
```

but finally got an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception' with
>   message 'Syntax error, unexpected token (, near to 'SELECT aa.nodeInd
>   FROM dNodes AS aa WHERE aa.f = 3) AS a ON n.aInd = a.nodeInd INNER
>   JOIN (SELECT bb.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS bb WHERE bb.f = 3) AS b ON
>   n.bInd = b.nodeInd;', when parsing: SELECT n.* FROM neighbours AS n
>   INNER JOIN (SELECT aa.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS aa WHERE aa.f = 3) AS a
>   ON n.aInd = a.nodeInd INNER JOIN (SELECT bb.nodeInd FROM dNodes AS bb
>   WHERE bb.f = 3) AS b ON n.bInd = b.nodeInd; (214)' in D:\Program
>   Files\wamp\www\FYP\api\api_neighbours.php on line 10

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [subqueries are not supported in PhQL](http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/528/phql-joining-subquery). You can gather connection iterface from your `DI()` and try to put a raw query into it:

```
//$connection = $app->getDI()->get('db');
$connection = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->get('db');
$neis = $connection->query($phql); // standard-SQL query
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally created a view in my database and a model in Phalcon RESTful web service. It's a little bit silly but works. Anyway, thanks for your explanation. ^^